# Showing image in window.open along with other data not working

Tags: javascript, image, window.open

I want show data from jsp together with an image in window.
Following is my js code:

```
function printPage(id)
{
   var html="<html>";
   html+="<head>";     
   html+="</head>";   
   html+= document.getElementById("img_13").innerHTML;
   html+= document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;      
var printWin =   window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=auto,height=auto,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,
resizable=0'); 
printWin.document.write(html);
printWin.document.write("<img alt='ALTERNATIVE' src='../Images/calender/cal2.jpg' />");
printWin.document.close();
printWin.focus();
printWin.print();
printWin.close(); 
}
```

From jsp I am calling it as below

```
 <div id="receipt"> 
 some data over here
 </div>
 <div id="img_13">
 </div>
 <input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printPage('receipt')" >
```

Here img_13 is css id created for that image. Its getting displayed on jsp but not in window through js.
I have also tried document.write() with relative path of image but still does not work.

Comment: I got solution for this.

Comment: Instead of using relative path                         src='../Images/calender/cal2.jpg'                                                         I used absolute path                                           src='/ProgectName/ImagesFolder/image_name.png'

Comment: Actually I have tried this before with absolute path                                                          '/ProgectName/WebContent/ImagesFolder/image_name.png'                                                    which is actual absolute path but it was not working.Now I have removed WebContent from path and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this.Instead of using relative path 
  `<img alt='ALTERNATIVE' src='../Images/calender/cal2.jpg' />`
I used absolute path 
  `<img alt='ALTERNATIVE' src='/ProgectName/Images/cal2.jpg'/>`

Actually I have tried this before with absolute path '/ProgectName/WebContent/ImagesFolder/image_name.png' which is actual absolute path but it was not working.Now I have removed WebContent from path and it worked.